# How to resolve the error 'Property is null or is not IEnumerable' in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm trying to making the following

```
<platform:TablePrac.Columns>
    <platform:TextColumn Caption="it"/>
    <platform:TextColumn Caption="is"/>
</platform:TablePrac.Columns>
```

But when I run this the error **'Property Columns is null or is not IEnumerable'** is occurred.

The code flow is following.

When I wrote like above .xaml code, the property named Columns set the value.
(Columns is defined like below)

```
public List<Column> Columns
{
    set
    {
        columns = value;
        SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value);
    }
    get
    {
        return (List<Column>)GetValue(ColumnsProperty);
    }
}

public class Column
{
    public string caption;
    public Type type;
}

public class TextColumn : Column
{
    public TextColumn() : base()
    {
        this.type = typeof(string);
    }

    public TextColumn(string cap) : base()
    {
        this.caption = cap;
        this.type = typeof(string);
    }

    public string Caption
    {
        set { caption = value; }
        get { return caption; }
    }

    public Type Type
    {
        get { return type; }
    }
}
```

As a **very similar case**, defining StackLayout and making new views in it like below

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="it"/>
    <Label Text="is"/>
</StackLayout>
```

is same in .cs code like below

```
StackLayout stack = new StackLayout
{
    Children =
    {
        new Label { Text = "it"},
        new Label { Text = "is"}
    }
};
```

So, I want to make property Columns work as StackLayout in .xaml but I don't know how. I spend two days to solve it.... I need your help
Thank you.

**(Plus, StackLayout and Children are defined like below**

StackLayout

```
public class StackLayout : Layout<View>
```

Layout

```
[Xamarin.Forms.ContentProperty("Children")]
public abstract class Layout<T> : Layout, IViewContainer<T>
where T : View
{
    public IList<T> Children { get; }

    ...
}
```

**)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not IEnumerable but Null value.

When using BindableProperty in Xamarin.Forms, you can assign a default value to the Property. For example, give default value 'new List()' solve this problem.
Follwing is my code, if you have same problem, check it.

**Before :**

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ColumnsProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Columns", typeof(List<Column>), typeof(TablePrac));

public List<Column> Columns
{
    set
    {
        SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value);
    }
    get
    {
        return (List<Column>)GetValue(ColumnsProperty);
    }
}
```

**After :**

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ColumnsProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Columns", typeof(IEnumerable<Column>), typeof(TablePrac), new List<Column>());

public IEnumerable<Column> Columns
{
    set
    {
        SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value);
    }
    get
    {
        return (IList<Column>)GetValue(ColumnsProperty);
    }
}
```

I convert type of return value of Columns to **IList** since in case of 'StackLayout's Children', the type of Children is **IList** type. There is no other reason.